# How to send exceptions to exceptionController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="mappedHandlers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="exceptionController" />
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="tiles/content/error" />
</bean>
```

I'm trying to send exceptions to a controller so I can create a redirect. If I comment out the mappedHandlers part then the error tile is displayed but it is only a tile. The rest of the tiles load normally. I need to make a redirect in the controller so I can show an error page not just an error tile.

I can't find enough information or an example how the exception invokes some method in exceptionController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the `mappedHandlers` property is for. This is saying that this exception resolver bean should only apply to exceptions **thrown by** the controllers listed in that property. It does *not* send the exceptions **to** that controller.

If you want to send a simple redirect, then you can do somrthing like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="redirect:/myErrorPage" />
</bean>
```

You will lose all information on the exception by doing this, though.

If you want to write custom code to handle exceptions, then I suggest writing your own implementation of `HandlerExceptionResolver` (probably a subclass of `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`), and using that instead of `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`.

Another alternative is to use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation style (see docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)).